# present for a future event

Tags: future-tense

After buying a record on the net, I received this message from the artist "hope you like it". I was wondering why it is not "**hope you will like it**", as I have not received the record yet, so it is future, I don't have the record right now.

Is it because as it was bought on the net, I had the possibility to listen to it before buying it.

Comment: It's perfectly natural to use present tense when referring to future events like this. Compare, for example, *I hope I win the lottery tomorrow*, where if you hear someone say *I hope I **will** win the lottery tomorrow* there's a good chance you're listening to a non-native speaker. Present as future is a common usage in English, and we nearly *always* tend to prefer simpler tenses wherever they're "acceptable".

Answer (score 1):

As @FumbleFingers also stated, it's perfectly normal to use the present tense to refer to events that would technically be described in the future tense (in idiomatic English, at least). This is most likely due to a contraction of the phrase "I hope you'll like it", as over time, the *ll* in *you'll* got melded more and more into the word *you*.